# How can I retrieve a saved PDF file in SQL Server, stored as binary?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, pdf, asp.net-core

I have checked many questions on StackOverflow, and also searched on many different websites for possible solutions, but I don't seem to find any answer. Some don't work, others are very old and don't work either.

I have saved `.pdf` files in SQL Server as binary. Seems to work. But I don't know how to retrieve the data and turn the `byte[]` back to the `.pdf` file and make it available for download.

This is my model, where I save the `.pdf` file in `byte[]`:

```
public class Language
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Certificate { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I upload into database:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(string name, IFormFile certificate)
{
    Language language = new Language()
    {
        Name = name
    };

    if(certificate.Length > 0)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await certificate.CopyToAsync(stream);
            language.Certificate = stream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    _context.Add(language);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

I would like it to be able to retrieve the data and then download it.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: What class are you using for the pdf file when you converted to bytes.

Comment: I am using IFormFile

Comment: Do you mean FromFile?  FromFile crates a string which wil corrupt pdf which is binary.  Better to use            byte[] pdf = File.ReadAllBytes("filename");
            File.WriteAllBytes("filename", pdf);

Comment: I will try this in another project. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an action to return the bytes:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCertificate(int id)
{
    var language = await _context.Languages.FindAsync(id);
    if (language == null)
        return NotFound();

    return File(language.Certificate, "application/pdf");
}
```

Then, you can simply link to this action.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "simply link to this action"? I have the same issue described by @Max.  PDF files are stored in SQL Server but how to render them in an HTML element becomes the question.  Are you suggesting use of an <embed> tag with a "src" attribute set to "controller/action"?  Or, is there a better method?